# could not unset url after display the MVC page

Tags: php, navigation, url-routing

i am new to MVC i have created a routing class below, it is working fine but when i go to the index page the navigation anchor href are correct. but when i move to other controller the url first string which is url-0 , is still the previous controller, which change all navigation href address base+previous controller, for e.g if i am on indexController/index which will display all the pages froom database. and when i want to call logincontroller through navigation anchor the logincontroller href change it becomes indecontroller/loginController/login. the correct login href address is loginController/login. my htaccess and routing class is below.and folder structure.

mvc app controllers indexcontroller.php userController.php
     model user.php page.php
     lib 
     core App.php Controller.php
includes navigation.php
style style.css
images 
js javscript
index.php

I hope some one can help me, i tried but so success yet Please Help Thanks in advance.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /socialNetwork
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-_]+)\.?([a-zA-Z]+)?$ index.php?url=$1&extension=$2 [QSA,L]


    class App
{
    protected $controller = 'indexController';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = array();
    public function __construct()
    {
        $url = $this->parseUrl();
        //print_r($url);
        if (isset($url[0]))
        {
            if (file_exists('app/controllers/'.$url[0].'.php'))
            {
                //$url = ('../app/controllers/'.$url[0].'.php');
                $this->controller = $url[0];
                //echo ($this->controller);
                unset($url[0]);
            }
            }       
        require_once('app/controllers/'.$this->controller.'.php');
        $this->controller = new $this->controller;
        if (isset($url[1]))
        {
            if (method_exists($this->controller,$url[1]))
            {
                $this->method = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
            }
        }
        $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : array();
        call_user_func_array(array($this->controller,$this->method),$this->params);
    }
    public function parseUrl()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['url']))
        {
            return $url =explode('/',filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'],'/'),FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    }
}
```

this is my index page.

```
<header>
<img width="960" height="100" src="http://localhost/socialNetwork/images/bgheader.png">
</header>
<?php 
include_once("include/navigation.php");?>
<section class="content">
<?php
require_once('app/init.php');
$app = new App;
?>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not have relative url's in your view files (html-files). Check out some common MVC-like PHP frameworks like Laravel or Symfony. They all have methods which provides you the full qualified url for you vew-files like: http://domain.tld/controller/param/... instead of /cobntroller/..

Implementing this should solve your problem.

For example check out Laravel. It's very easy to understand and pretty flexible. There you have access to all your route with functions like `Redirect::route('your-route-name')`. The routing engine will then translate this into the full url!

EDIT: Just to be more precise, laravel is not a real mvc by definition. But in some parts it acts like a mvc.

Hope this helps

Comment: This just illustrates that you have no understanding what MVC even is. Let me educate you: MVC is an architectural pattern which defines the constraints for information flow between application's layers. In proper MVC you have two major layers: presentation layer and model layer. Frameworks have no effect on that.

Comment: I know what a MVC ist and I also understand the architectural pattern. There is no need "to educate me".

Comment: But let me cite the Laravel-Book: "[..] This is a hint that Laravel follows the model-view-controller (MVC) architectural pattern, which enforces a separation between “business logic” from the input and presentation logic associated with a graphical user interface (GUI). In the case of Laravel web applications, the business logic typically consists of data models for things like users, blog posts, and the GUI is just a web page in a web browser. The MVC design pattern is very popular in the web development space. [..]"

Comment: @DavidC. there are alot of PHP framework that say they use MVC. But they do not. It is known fact. The "MVC" that CodeIgniter, Cake, Laravel and etc use is not MVC, eventough there are tons of resources on the net saying they are. Instead of fighting this fact, try to embrace it and how complex this stuff really is..

Comment: @RonniSkansing yes, I know that fact! But thank you anyway for your comment. I had lot's of discussions about MVC's and (not only) in my opinion this topic is handled far to static. But anyway, I'm surprised of downvoting my Answer because the original question was not 'what are mvc'. And I really recommend you guys to give a answer instead of 'educating' s.b. in mvc. I'm not a coder, I'm a scientist. But I won't start a discussion about good scientifical practice here.

Comment: I did not downvote you. But the comment you made on (and the source you pulled out) MVC just made me throw a comment.

Comment: Sorry for confuse you! The point about downvoting goes to @tereško who  turned this topic into a discussion about MVC in general :)